Degree of extension of the field of coefficients of modular forms
I am beginning to study modular forms and I came across an inequality defining the bound for the degree of extension of the field of coefficients of a modular form $f\in S_k(\Gamma_1(N))$. This goes as follows
$$[K_f/\mathbb{Q}]\leq \text{rank}_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{T}(S_k^{\text{}new}(\Gamma_1(N)))$$
where $\mathbb{T}$ is the algebra of Hecke operators acting on $S_k^{\text{}new}(\Gamma_1(N))$.
Is this true for any level and weight? If it is can anyone give or refer me to the proof of this?

Where did you come across this inequality? And what do you mean by $\mathbb{T}$?

Sorry for my unclear question earlier. I have edited it now. By \mathcal{T}, I meant the algebra of Hecke operators. You can find it here https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~pbruin/coefficients.pdf. It doesn't gives a proof or mentions any reference though.

I'm sure there's a better way, but this implicitly follows from methods of computing modular forms using modular symbols. See for instance Algorithm 9.14 at https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/newforms.html.

Yes, this is true regardless of level and weight, provided that $f$ is a normalized newform. The point is that $T_n \in \mathbb{T}\otimes \mathbb{Q} \longmapsto a_n(f) \in K_f$ is a surjective ring homomorphism.
It is (much) more difficult to show that $\mathbb{T}\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra (in fact, that $\mathbb{T}$ is a finite free $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra), and that newforms correspond exactly to ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{T} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (whence, for instance, the fact that the Galois-conjugate of a newform is a newform).
One way to go about this is to use modular symbols as hinted in davidlowryduda’s comments: you construct a finitely generated abelian group of modular symbols $S := H^1_{par}(\Gamma_1(N),V_{k-2}(\mathbb{Z}))$ and an isomorphism $S \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C} \simeq \mathcal{S}_k(\Gamma_1(N))$. Then you can show that under this isomorphism, the action of $\mathbb{T}$ on the RHS comes from an action of $\mathbb{T}$ on $S$.
I suggest Gabor Wiese’s notes on this topic https://math.uni.lu/~wiese/notes/MFII.pdf.
